# Problem with connection to apache after scaling up, my stateful database on Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, hpa

Hiii!!!

i have deployed to Kubernetes keyrock, apache and mysql..

After i used the hpa and my stateful database scaled up, i can't login to my simple site..
This is my sql code:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:5.7.21
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 50Mi #50
              cpu: 50m
            limits:
                memory: 500Mi #220?
                cpu: 400m #65  
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              subPath: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret # MARK P
                  key: password
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret # MARK P
                  key: host                  
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mysql-storage
      spec:
        accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: standard #?manual
        resources:
            requests:
                storage: 5Gi
```

And it's headless service:

```
# Headless service for stable DNS entries of StatefulSet members.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql  #x-app  #
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mysql  #x-app
```

Anyone can help me?

I'm using gke.. Keyrock and apache are deployments and mysql is statefulset..

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just scale up a Standalone database. Using HPA for stateless application works but not for stateful applications like a database.

Increasing replica of your StaetefulSet will just create another pod with a new MySQL instance. This new replica isn't aware of the data in your old replica.  Basically, you now have completely two different databases. That's why you can't login after scaling up. When your request get routed to the new replica, this instance does not have the user info that you created in the old replica.

In this case, you should deploy your database in clustered mode. Then, you can take advantage of horizontal scaling.

I recommend to use a database operator like [mysql/mysql-operator](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-operator), [presslabs/mysql-operator](https://github.com/presslabs/mysql-operator), or [KubeDB](https://kubedb.com/) to manage your database in Kubernetes. Out of these operators, KubeDB has autoscaling feature. I am not sure that other operators provide this feature.

**Disclosure:** I am one of the developer of KubeDB operator.

Comment: omg.. Thank you very very much!! I'm so lucky, you saw my question!! You helped me a lot!!! I had misunderstood statefulsets.. I thought that the second db, was a copy of the first.. Υour answer answers another question I asked!! Thank you, again..

Comment: could you answer me another question for operators? i will deploy it in the same namespace, with my deployment? And how i can connect it with keyrock? Thank youu!

Comment: And a last question.. my database will be a deployment or a sts?

Comment: Obviously, StatefulSet. Your database could be in the same namespace as your application or different namespace.

Comment: hmm ookk i see... i tried to create the operator, i deleted everything and the 2nd time i tried to deploy it, my innodbcluster stuck on initializing.. i can't find why.. Do you have any idea? Thank you again!!!

Comment: Which operator are you using?

Comment: I used the first one you mentioned,  mysql/mysql-operator.. Seemed the simplest..   
First time i created the yaml files, everything was running ..  But i couldn't connect it with my cluster and keyrock so i deleted everything and now  **innodbcluster** stuck on **initializing**..  So i can't use **kubectl port-forward service/mycluster mysql** ..Also **replicaset.apps/mycluster-router** is not ready.. I tried to delete everything again but mycluster-0 pod, stuck on terminating..  Thank you very much again!!